# How to add "0" to multiple parts of text value in Field Calculator with Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I have values in a text column that are as follows:

```
000_100

100_200

...

1000_1100

1100_1200
```

I want it to read:

```
0000_0100

0100_0200

...

1000_1100

1100_1200
```

I want all values to have the same number of characters, for example 9. The numbers in the hundreds separated by the "_" need a "0" infront for this to be accomplished. I saw that I can use zfill to add a "0" to the beginning, but is there a way to specify where to put a second "0"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `zfill` string method, along with some basic string splitting/joining, will let you do this very slickly:

```
def update_text(old_text):
    new_text_parts = [num.zfill(4) for num in old_text.split('_')]
    new_text = '_'.join(new_text_parts)
    return new_text
```

If you would prefer not to bother with a function in the Field Calculator code block, you can simplify this (as Mike T commented) to a single expression:

```
'_'.join(num.zfill(4) for num in !field!.split('_'))
```

Comment: or as a simple expression for ArcGIS: `'_'.join(s.zfill(4) for s in !field!.split('_'))`

Comment: Why would you need double parentheses? I tried them, and both work fine.

Comment: Hmm, I could swear I've received errors before without explicitly using a generator or list in `join`. Must have been another method I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Field Calculator, you can create a new field of text type and calculate the field to be:

```
def updateValue(textField):
  newval = textField.split('_')
  if len(newval[0]) == 3:
    newval[0] = '0' + newval[0]
  if len(newval[1]) == 3:
    newval[1] = '0' + newval[1]
  total_val = newval[0] + '_' + newval[1]
  return total_val
```

Remember to use the Advanced block as outlined in the [Calculate Field examples](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004s000000) (look at the Using code blocks section).

```
updateValue(!your_text_field!)
```